# Construção de variáveis novas usando o dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho o seguinte banco de dados

```
Clientes.Dep..Gratuito.PCG Clientes.Dep..Gratuito Clientes.Dep..Não.Gratuito
                     0                      0                          0
                     0                      0                          0
                    25                      0                          0
                     0                      0                          2
                     0                      0                         79
                     0                      0                         71
Clientes.Usu..Gratuito.PCG Clientes.Usu..Gratuito Clientes.Usu..Não.Gratuito
                    21                      0                          0
                    50                      0                          0
                     0                      0                          0
                    58                      0                          1
                     0                      0                          0
                     0                      0                         16
```

O que eu quero é construir duas variáveis `Clientes.Dep` e `Clientes.Usu` utilizando o pacote `dplyr`, e essas colunas seriam a soma de tudo que envolve `Dep.` e `Usu.`, respectivamente Um exemplo das minhas tentativas é

```
CLIENTES %>% 
  mutate(Clientes.Dep = rowSums(select(contains("Dep."))),
     Clientes.Usu = rowSums(select(contains("Usu."))))
```

mas sem sucesso.

Segue um `dput` dos dados

```
structure(list(Clientes.Dep..Gratuito.PCG = c(0, 0, 25, 0, 0, 
0), Clientes.Dep..Gratuito = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Clientes.Dep..Não.Gratuito = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 79, 71), Clientes.Usu..Gratuito.PCG = c(21, 50, 0, 58, 0, 0),
Clientes.Usu..Gratuito = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Clientes.Usu..Não.Gratuito = c(0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 16)), .Names = c("Clientes.Dep..Gratuito.PCG", "Clientes.Dep..Gratuito", 
"Clientes.Dep..Não.Gratuito", "Clientes.Usu..Gratuito.PCG", "Clientes.Usu..Gratuito", 
"Clientes.Usu..Não.Gratuito"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui resolver, estava faltando incluir um `.` dentro da função `select`

```
CLIENTES %>% 
  mutate(CLIENTES.Dep = rowSums(select(., contains("Dep."))),
         CLIENTES.Usu = rowSums(select(., contains("Usu."))))
```